# Converting Char array to Long in C

Tags: c, memory

This question may looks silly, but please guide me
I have a function to convert long data to char array

```
void ConvertLongToChar(char *pSrc, char *pDest)
{
    pDest[0] = pSrc[0];
    pDest[1] = pSrc[1];
    pDest[2] = pSrc[2];
    pDest[3] = pSrc[3];
}
```

And I call the above function like this

```
long lTemp = (long) (fRxPower * 1000);
ConvertLongToChar ((char *)&lTemp, pBuffer);
```

Which works fine.
I need a similar function to reverse the procedure. Convert char array to long.
I cannot use atol or similar functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leaving the burden of matching the endianness with your other function to you, here's one way:

```
unsigned long int l = pdest[0] | (pdest[1] << 8) | (pdest[2] << 16) | (pdest[3] << 24);
```

Just to be safe, here's the corresponding other direction:

```
unsigned char pdest[4];
unsigned long int l;
pdest[0] = l         & 0xFF;
pdest[1] = (l >>  8) & 0xFF;
pdest[2] = (l >> 16) & 0xFF;
pdest[3] = (l >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Going from `char[4]` to long and back is entirely reversible; going from long to `char[4]` and back is reversible for values up to 2^32-1.

Note that all this is only well-defined for unsigned types.

(My example is *little* endian if you read `pdest` from left to right.)

*Addendum:* I'm also assuming that `CHAR_BIT == 8`. In general, substitute multiples of 8 by multiples of `CHAR_BIT` in the code.

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
union {
 unsigned char c[4];
 long l;
} conv;

conv.l = 0xABC;
```

and access `c[0] c[1] c[2] c[3]`. This is good as it wastes no memory and is very fast because there is no shifting or any assignment besides the initial one and it works both ways.

Comment: It is also, according to the C++ standard, undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @jalf This is a C question.

Comment: @NickWiggill fair enough. It is also, according to the C standard, undefined behavior. :)

Comment: this is not UB under gcc and MS compiler I am pretty sure. It probably is by the C std.

Comment: ^ What compilers do isn't actually informative at all about what the Standard says, though you happened to be correct anyway. @jalf No, C made type-punning via a `union` well-specified in C99 onwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified C++ did **not** inherit this, however.

Answer (score 10):

A simple way would be to use memcpy:

```
char * buffer = ...;
long l;
memcpy(&l, buff, sizeof(long));
```

That does not take endianness into account, however, so beware if you have to share data between multiple computers.

Comment: I tried your example but it did not work for me. What did, was something very similar: ```char* vIn = "0";
long vOut = strtol(vIn,NULL,10);
```

Comment: @Beezer That does a very different thing: your method parses text into a number, while mine interprets the bytes of a buffer as a long. These are different problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to treat `sizeof (long)` bytes memory as a single long, then you should do the below:

```
char char_arr[sizeof(long)];
long l;

memcpy (&l, char_arr, sizeof (long));
```

This thing can be done by pasting each bytes of the long using bit shifting ans pasting, like below.

```
l = 0;
l |= (char_arr[0]);
l |= (char_arr[1] << 8);
l |= (char_arr[2] << 16);
l |= (char_arr[3] << 24);
```

If you mean to convert "1234\0" string into 1234L then you should

```
l = strtol (char_arr, NULL, 10); /* to interpret the base as decimal */
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long ConvertCharToLong(char *pSrc) {
    int i=1;
    long result = (int)pSrc[0] - '0';
    while(i<strlen(pSrc)){
         result = result * 10 + ((int)pSrc[i] - '0');
         ++i;
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    char* str = "34878";
    printf("The answer is %d",ConvertCharToLong(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It wont work as we the char array dont store direct long value it store in bytes, thanks for your answer

Comment: you are correct with your example. In My case it is not the long data but bytes it is storing, so this solution not works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long long convert_achar_to_unsigned_long_long(char *src) {
  unsigned long long ret = 0;
  char digit[2];
  digit[1] = '\0';
  byte n = 0;
  while(src[n] != '\0') {    
    digit[0] = src[n];
    if(n!=0) {
      ret *= 10;
    }  
    ret += atoi(digit);
    n++;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: This implementation is irrelevant for the OP's question and rather inefficient for its purpose: check for a digit and use `src[n] - '0'` instead of `atoi(digit)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is dirty but it works:

```
unsigned char myCharArray[8];
// Put some data in myCharArray here...
long long integer = *((long long*) myCharArray);
```

Comment: and this is wrong, aliasing error and possible undefined behaviour from wrong alignment

Answer (score -1):

```
char charArray[8]; //ideally, zero initialise
unsigned long long int combined = *(unsigned long long int *) &charArray[0];
```

Be wary of strings that are null terminated, as you will end up copying any bytes *beyond* the null terminator into `combined`; thus in the above assignment, `charArray` needs to be fully zero-initialised for a "clean" conversion.

Comment: and this is wrong, aliasing error and possible undefined behaviour from wrong alignment

Answer (score -1):

Just found this having tried more than one of the above to no avail :=( :

```
    char * vIn = "0";
    long vOut = strtol(vIn,NULL,10);
```

Worked perfectly for me.
To give credit where it is due, this is where I found it:
https://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-char-Array-to-long-in-C.html