# Cast byte array to float

Tags: c++, c, casting

I have a program that needs to take in 4 bytes and convert them to an IEEE-754 float. The bytes are transferred out of order, but I can put them back in order just fine. My problem is casting them to a float. The relevant parts of code:

```
//Union to store bytes and float on top of each other
typedef union {
    unsigned char b[4];
    float f;
} bfloat;

//Create instance of the union
bfloat Temperature;

//Add float data using transmitted bytes
MMI.Temperature.b[2] = 0xD1;//MMIResponseMsg[7];
MMI.Temperature.b[3] = 0xE1;//MMIResponseMsg[8];
MMI.Temperature.b[0] = 0x41;//MMIResponseMsg[9];
MMI.Temperature.b[1] = 0xD7;//MMIResponseMsg[10];

//Attempting to read the float value
lWhole=(long) ((float)MMI.Temperature.f);
//DEBUGGING
stevenFloat = (float)MMI.Temperature.f;
```

`lWhole` is a long and `stevenFloat` is a float. When debugging I can see that the values I assign to the byte array are being stored correctly, however the values of `stevenFloat` and `lWhole` are incorrect. They seem to hover close to 0, or close to the max float/long values. A long and float are both 32 bits with my compiler.

Does anyone know why this isn't working? It looked correct to me when I received the code to work on and it appears to be a common solution online, I am just stumped.

Comment: Are you sure they're being transferred out of order? When I put in `0x41d7d1e1` into a hex to float converter, I got ~27, which seems like a nice number.

Comment: what would you expect to obtain from `0xD1E141D7`?

Comment: That might be my issue, I put those constants in incorrectly. As transferred it would be D1-E1-41-D7

Comment: @H2C03 Confirmed on my machine, swap the bytes in each word (3,2,1,0) and you'll be fine.

Comment: As a suggestion, create a `bFloat` and explicitly assign the `bFloat::f` value to be the expected value.  Then examine `bFloat::b` to see what the actual bytes come out to be, and it may give you the clue you need to fix your problem

Comment: Just use `memcpy`. Reading from a union member that hasn't been directly initialized is undefined behavior.

Comment: @GManNickG: It is undefined in C++, but not in C. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, this is an endianness issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    union {
        uint8_t bytes[4];
        float f;
    } fun1 = { .bytes = { 0x41, 0xd7, 0xd1, 0xe1} }, fun2 = { .bytes = { 0xe1, 0xd1, 0xd7, 0x41} };

    printf("%f\n%f\n", fun1.f, fun2.f);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
-483860023749617123328.000000
26.977480
```

Comment: how did you decide that `-483860023749617123328.000000` is better than `26.977480`

Comment: @triclosan Perhaps because `-483860023749617123328.000000` is a physical impossibility, be it in Celsius, Fahrenheit or Kelvin degrees?

Comment: @H2CO3: Maybe it measures the temperature at the center of the sun in picokelvin...

Comment: Isn't there any other faster and shorter method do the same. This is little ugly if we have several of above and larger arrays to convert.

Comment: For C++, this results in undefined behavior. I'm not sure whether it is undefined in C.