# Is this strict aliasing example correct?

Tags: c++, c, strict-aliasing

I've been reading up on the strict aliasing rules over the last week or so and ran into this article: [Understanding C/C++ Strict Aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html).

The article goes through several ways two swap the halves of a 32-bit integer, giving both good examples and ones that violate the strict aliasing rule.  I'm having trouble understanding one of the examples, though.

This code is described as broken.

```
uint32_t
swaphalves(uint32_t a)
{
    a = (a >> 16) | (a << 16);
    return a;
}
```

The reason given is:

> This version looks reasonable, but you don't know if the right and left sides of the
>   | will each get the original version of `a` or if one of them will get the result of 
>   the other. There's no sequence point here, so we don't know anything about the order of
>   operations here, and you may get different results from the same compiler using different
>   levels of optimization.

I disagree.  This code looks fine to me.  There is only one write to `a` in the `a = (a >> 16 | (a << 16);` line, and I expect that both reads of `a` take place before that write.  Further, there are no pointers or references and no incompatible types.

Am I missing a strict aliasing violation in this code, or is the article incorrect?

Comment: Is this in a single threaded scenario?

Comment: That would be my assumption, though I don't think it's explicitly stated in the article.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae If not, it's broken for reasons entirely unrelated to strict aliasing and sequence points, and only having one read on the right hand side won't fix it.

Comment: This example is clearly incorrect. If this scenario was right, then you couldn't code at all. I mean, with the same argument `a = a + a` should not work, either. All in all: don't ever trust this consulting firm.

Comment: @delnan Absolutely, I'm just not finding anything that could make the above code faulty - other than race conditions.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Well there's always the option that the article OP refers to is wrong ;-)

Comment: The strict aliasing articles I reference in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801) are way better sources.

Comment: There's only UB if one of those is `<<=` or `>>=`, or potentially if `a` is signed, but then the UB is obvious. Also, we are talking about a local variable here. Threading doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no pointers and references anywhere in this code, so strict aliasing rules don't even enter the picture. And indeed the author invokes *sequence points* rather than strict aliasing to justify the assertion that it's undefined. However, it seems this reasoning is wrong and the code snippet has perfectly defined semantics. As [Prasoon Saurav explains in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183735/395760):

> (§1.9/15) The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.

So regarding the `=` operator, the evaluation of `a` and  `(a >> 16) | (a << 16)` are sequenced before the assignment. Neither of those is problematic: Although its parts are all unsequenced relative to each other, no write to `a` remains that would need to be sequenced.

(Technically this raises the question of how the side effect of the assignment is sequenced w.r.t. its value computation, but I couldn't find anything on this. Presumably it's somewhere in the standard but I don't have a copy handy. I *strongly* suspect it's sequenced after the value computation for the reasons in the next paragraph.)

You could also apply common sense: The write to `a` needs to evaluate `(a >> 16) | (a << 16)` first *to write the right value* and hence it can't happen in the middle of that evaluation. Another issue with the article is that even if

```
uint32_t
swaphalves(uint32_t a)
{
    a = (a >> 16) | (a << 16);
    return a;
}
```

had undefined behavior due to sequence points,

```
uint32_t
swaphalves(uint32_t a)
{
    return (a >> 16) | (a << 16);
}
```

wouldn't (there are no writes to be sequenced) and hence the far more complicated versions (unions, memcpy) that take up most of the rest of the article are pointless.

Comment: so… to sum up: `a = (a >> 16) | (a << 16);` is perfectly OK, defined behaviour?