# reinterpret_cast structure to a fixed size array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, reinterpret-cast

I have a structure `S` that packs together two fixed size arrays of type `T`.

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    array<array<T, 20>, 10> x1;
    array<T, 10> x2;
};
```

I want to get a reference to a uni-dimensional array of elements of type `T` of size 210. I tried to use `reinterpret_cast`, but the compiler won't accept this:

```
S<T> s;
array<T, 210>& x = *reinterpret_cast<S*>(&s);
```

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29277949/1478624) works:

```
  S<T> s;
  T* x = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&s);
```

but is there a way to get a reference to a fixed size unidimensional array from that structure? I tried using `#pragma pack(pop, 1)` with no success.

Comment: Your casting seems... suspect. Why do you want that? This question seems to be [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have several different types (machine learning models) that have a large set of parameters. In order to use its own parameters efficiently, each type holds them packed in one or more multi-dimensional arrays. Separately I have a generic function that optimizes any number of parameters regardless of the model they come from.

Comment: Mind the strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<array<T, 210>&>(s)` should do that, if that's really what you want.

It should be well-defined, since these are standard layout types (assuming that `T` is). But you're skating on thin ice.

Comment: Oh... sure. I just didn't see it. Thanks for your time. Yes, I will allow the template instantiation only if `is_standard_layout<T>`.