# strict aliasing in C

Tags: c, gcc, strict-aliasing

Question about type punning: why does this code break strict aliasing rules:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    short j;

    printf("%i\n", j = *((short*)&a));
    return 0;
}
```

and this is not:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    short j;
    int *p; 

    p=&a;
    printf("%i\n", j = *((short*)p));
    return 0;
}
```

Build by `gcc -fstrict-aliasing`.

Thank you!

Comment: because a and j are point to the same memory as different types?

Comment: Both do. Compiler don't guarantee a warning. Try different aliasing detection types (`-Wstrict-aliasing=n`, where n is 1, 2 or 3).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They both violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801), I am going to quote my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801) which says  (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> code violates the [strict aliasing rules](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) which **makes it illegal to access an object through a pointer of a different type**, although access through a  char * is allowed. The compiler is allowed to assume that pointers of different types do not point to the same memory and optimize accordingly.

`gcc` is a little more detailed in the documetation of `-Wstrict-aliasing=n` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) which says:

> This option is only active when -fstrict-aliasing is active. It warns about code that might break the strict aliasing rules that the compiler is using for optimization. **Higher levels correspond to higher accuracy (fewer false positives)**. Higher levels also correspond to more effort, similar to the way -O works. -Wstrict-aliasing is equivalent to -Wstrict-aliasing=3.

and describes each level as follows:

> - Level 1: Most aggressive, quick, least accurate. Possibly useful when
>     higher levels do not warn but -fstrict-aliasing still breaks the code,
>     as it has very few false negatives. However, it has many false
>     positives. Warns for all pointer conversions between possibly
>     incompatible types, even if never dereferenced. Runs in the front end
>     only.
> - Level 2: Aggressive, quick, not too precise. May still have many false
>     positives (not as many as level 1 though), and few false negatives
>     (but possibly more than level 1). Unlike level 1, it only warns when
>     an address is taken. Warns about incomplete types. Runs in the front
>     end only.
> - Level 3 (default for -Wstrict-aliasing): Should have very few false
>     positives and few false negatives. Slightly slower than levels 1 or 2
>     when optimization is enabled. **Takes care of the common pun+dereference
>     pattern in the front end: `*(int*)&some_float`.** If optimization is
>     enabled, it also runs in the back end, where it deals with multiple
>     statement cases using flow-sensitive points-to information. Only warns
>     when the converted pointer is dereferenced. Does not warn about
>     incomplete types.

So it is not guaranteed to catch all instances and different levels have different degrees of accuracy.

Typically the effect you are looking for can be accomplished using type punning through a union, which I cover in my linked answer above and [gcc explicitly supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning).