# Casting char[] to usigned int gives: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, strict-aliasing

I have a line in some legacy's source code:

```
#define MAXMSG 1024
...
char m_recvBuf[MAXMSG];
unsigned int msgLength = ntohl(*((unsigned int *)m_recvBuf));
```

This yields the following warning:

```
x.cpp: In member function ‘bool xx::cccc(std::string&)’:
x.cpp:308: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

How can I get rid of this warning ?

my compile line:

```
g++ -c -g -O2 -Wall -DDEBUG_ON -D_VERSION_=\"1.0.0\" `xml2-config --cflags` -I../src -I./common -I. -I../../test/ -o common/xx.o common/xx.cpp

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
```

Comment: Use compiler option `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  This code violates the standard and in -O3 mode gcc might optimize it out entirely , however the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option causes it to behave as if you want to access the memory in the char buffer.

Comment: You could also consider fixing the code, e.g. `unsigned int msgLength; memcpy(&msgLength, m_recvBuf, sizeof msgLength); msgLength = ntohl(msgLength);`, or even better, do a portable conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that violates [strict aliasing rules](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) and thus it's potentially unsafe.

You can either hide the warning with `-Wno-strict-aliasing` (this won't solve your problem), modify your data structure or avoid the problem entirely by specifying position and length of your binary copy as Matt suggested (probably the best option):

```
unsigned int msgLength; 
memcpy(&msgLength, m_recvBuf, sizeof(msgLength)); 
msgLength = ntohl(msgLength);
```

**Notice:** I've not been getting the error with clang 3.4 and gcc 4.8.2 in -O3, that means the compiler might have optimized the warning away. Anyway that doesn't assure you your code is safe.

Comment: I personally prefer to [this article](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) on strict aliasing to the QT one.

Comment: Also note, as I mention in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118277/1708801) the strict aliasing checks are not guaranteed to catch strict aliasing violations. So no warning does not mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous responders have said you can alter the compile flags to make the warning go away. If you're open to a little light refactoring though, you can solve the issue more cleanly with a union like this:

```
#define MAXMSG 1024

union {
  char buf[MAXMSG];
  unsigned int length;
} recvbuf;

// [ read your message stream to recvbuf.buf ]

unsigned int msgLength = ntohl(recvbuf.length);
```

Comment: Note that type punning through a union is technically undefined behavior in C++ but most compiler support it. You can learn a bit more in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801).