# dereferncing type-punned pointer will break strict aliasing rules

Tags: c++, c, gcc-warning, avr32, avr32-gcc

I am using AVR32 Studio studio to compile my code for AVRUC3 controller.
When I switched to Optimization level -O2(optimization more) ,this pointer warnings " dereferncing type-punned pointer will break strict aliasing rules  " started to appear.
I know why I am getting this warnings...

**But My question is Should I run my code with -O2 and solve this all errors OR is it OK enough to continue having them and compile with -O0(No optimization).**

Comment: yes, you should fix these errors as they result in UB.

Comment: gcc strict aliasing warnings are [subject to false negatives/positives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118277/1708801) and can be effected by optimization level etc... just because the warning goes away does not mean it is not undefined behavior.

Comment: It would help to see an example of a type punned pointer that the compiler is complaining about. Windows API uses a lot of [type punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union) in structures, usually via unions, and it's not an issue there.

Comment: @rcgldr yes but [gcc explicitly supports type punning via a union](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31080901/1708801) even using strict-aliasing. Although I agree an example of the code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone