# g++'s strict-aliasing warning accuracy

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

[GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says that `-Wstrict-aliasing=3` is the most accurate level and that lower levels are more likely to give false positives.

I believe the following examples all violate the strict aliasing rule:

```
float violate1(float a_float)
{
    float * f_data(&a_float);
    int * i_data((int *)f_data);
    int value(*i_data);
    return value + a_float;
}

float violate2(float a_float)
{
    int * i_data((int *)&a_float);
    int value(*i_data);
    return value + a_float;
}

float violate3(float *f_data)
{
    int * i_data((int *)f_data);
    int value(*i_data);
    return value + *f_data;
}
```

Yet g++ only gives warnings for them all when `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` is used.
With `-Wstrict-aliasing=3` no warnings are issued:  https://godbolt.org/g/aox2S1

Are the examples in fact not violations or is it that GCC's warnings are not a reliable indication of violations?

Comment: fwiw warnings cannot be 100% reliable, if they were they would probably be errors

Comment: Those are strict aliasing violation. 3 is more accurate: less false positives, but miss some true positives, 1 got more true positives, but also more false positives.

Comment: Related [strict aliasing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25117826/1708801)

Answer (score 3):

The strict-aliasing rule is stated in very clear terms from [[basic.lval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#11)

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object [...]

This would mean `violate1` and `violate2` is the same thing and is necessarily a violation.

An object pointer [can be casted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#12) to and from another arbitrary object pointer type, the result is the original pointer. In `violate3`, if `f_data` is an `int*` previously casted to `float*`, there would be no violation with `*i_data`, but then it would be a violation at `*f_data`