# Is conversion between exactly-sized integers always completely defined by the standard?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    auto x=std::uint32_t(1)<<31;
    std::cout << " x: 0x" << std::hex << x << " =  " << std::dec << x << "\n";
    int32_t sx=x;
    std::cout << "sx: 0x" << std::hex << sx << " = " << std::dec << sx << "\n";
}
```

I get the following output from it:

```
 x: 0x80000000 =  2147483648
sx: 0x80000000 = -2147483648
```

Here the value of `x` can't be represented in `int32_t`, and the C++11 Standard says the following about this conversion:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Is this still implementation-defined even with `intXX_t`, for which we have certain guarantees on representation?
If yes, then how can I guarantee that the result will be as shown above? Should I `memcpy` my unsigned value to signed to get two's complement interpretation, or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: `memcpy` from one type to another would give undefined behaviour, so that's not an ideal workaround.

Comment: @AlanStokes according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405129/) it seems to not give UB.

Comment: One way to "solve" this is to limit portability to systems where *implementation-defined* means that it works as expected. On systems where the conversion traps you are likely to have much worse problems than this.

Comment: That link says `memcpy` obeys the aliasing rules, so it's ok if you know the layout of the types. But you don't in general know the layout of `int32_t`, although it is guaranteed to use 2s complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int32_t sx=x;` is *implementation-defined*.

The rule, which you quoted, is that converting a value to a type for which that value is out-of-range causes implementation-defined behaviour.

The range for `int32_t` goes up to `INT32_MAX` which is `2147483647`,  but `(uint32_t)1 << 31` is one more than that.

It's nothing to do with representations, it's all about whether the value can remain unchanged or not.

Using `memcpy` would generate the `int32_t` which has the same representation as the other value you copy from (I think this is well-defined since `int32_t` cannot have padding or traps)

Comment: Using `memcpy` should work, but it needs a stronger guarantee than what you put in your answer. It matters that the C standard specifies that `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are *corresponding* signed and unsigned integer types, which basically means their representations have to match, with the unsigned version's highest value bit mapping to the signed version's sign bit. Without that requirement, a malicious implementation could make one of them big-endian, and the other one little-endian.

Comment: @hvd Is there a similar guarantee in C++?

Comment: @AlanStokes That guarantee applies to C++ too, because C++ specifies that `int32_t` and `uint32_t` (if present) mean the same thing they do in C.

Comment: @hvd Yes, and the strict aliasing rule specifically allows this case

Comment: @M.M Ah, right! So that *should* mean `memcpy` isn't needed, and `int32_t sx=(int32_t&)x;` should work too.

Comment: @user743382 unfortunately(?) reference type-punning is strict-aliasing UB, just like `*(int32_t*)&x`.  You need memcpy in ISO C++, or your own copying via `unsigned char*` which is allowed to alias anything.  (Or in some C++ implementations, union type punning is well-defined as an extension.  And in some (like MSVC), pointer-casting *is* well-defined, like gcc/clang `-fno-strict-aliasing`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is implementation defined.

There are values that an unsigned 32 bit integral type (such as `uint32_t`) can represent that a signed 32 bit integral type (`int32_t`) cannot be guaranteed able to represent.   One of those values is being produced in your code.   Hence the clause you quoted from C++11 is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is implementation defined because 2's compliment is not guaranteed. (Imagine a separate sign bit).

Thus no safe mechanism would exist.

Comment: `int32_t ` is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits and 2's complement. Otherwise the typedef will not be present.

Comment: @Bo Persson,  where is representation guaranteed to be two's compliment.  I am not aware of any strange implementations,  but I think they would be compliant