# unsigned conversion in C works as expected on x86 but not ARM

Tags: c, gcc, x86, type-conversion, arm

I am facing a problem running a C program on ARM processor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float f = -40.000000;
    unsigned int a = f;

    printf("\t Actual TX Power = %0.2f dBm \n",
         (double)(int)a);

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
on x86-        Actual TX Power = -40.00 dBm
on ARM-        Actual TX Power = -0.00 dBm
```

The value survives the round-trip on x86 but not ARM.

I am not able to figure out what is the issue. What could be the reason behind it.

Comment: It looks like the result depends on optimization level.  `gcc -O1` on x86-64 makes it print `0.0` (not `-0.0`), while `-O0` prints `-40.0`.  So there's an [MCVE] here just on x86 (32 or 64-bit code).

Comment: Converting a negative number to an `unsigned` gives you a large number. Converting that into `int` produces an overflow. You cannot expect any consistent behaviour from that.

Comment: `clang -target aarch64 -c foo.c` (optimization disabled) and linking with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc foo.o` also produces `0.0` under `qemu-aarch64`, unlike on x86, so there's a cross-platform difference, too, within the same compiler.  https://godbolt.org/z/HVmfPK shows AArch64 clang codegen.

Comment: Compilers can optimise this very hard: https://godbolt.org -ARM GCC 8.3.1 clocks the correct result as `0` and omits any floating point.

Comment: @JensGustedt: that's not the actual problem.  In real life on 2's complement systems, unsigned -> 2's complement conversion just uses the same bit-pattern unchanged.  (It might be UB or unspecified in C, but in practice compilers let you get away with this.)  Anyway, if you print `a`, you'll see that *it* is also `0`, because that's the nearest representable `unsigned` to `-40`.  (AArch64 gcc uses `fcvtzu` to convert directly to unsigned with saturation to the value-range of unsigned, unlike x86 where it converts to signed 64-bit and takes the low half, if you disable optimization to hide UB.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes it is. Doing so is just undefined, and compilers do (or run into) code that may make no sense to you.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, it's UB in ISO C.  That wasn't the point I was making, though.  This program encounters UB *before* that, in converting `-40.0f` to `unsigned` (see dups).  That doesn't "give a large number", it's UB on the spot.  But the actual point I was making is that despite large unsigned -> int being UB, *that* UB doesn't explain the actual behaviour the OP is seeing.  In practice you can always get away with round-tripping an unsigned to `int` and back on GCC for x86 and ARM.  (Not that you should, just that it doesn't explain this interesting practical difference in what UB led to.)

Comment: @JensGustedt: correction: `unsigned`->`int` overflow is [*implementation defined*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806954/is-conversion-between-exactly-sized-integers-always-completely-defined-by-the-st), not UB.  [ISO C17  § 6.3.1.3 .3](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#page=57)