# Will this strict-aliasing rule violation have the behavior I expect?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

I know violating the strict-aliasing rule is Undefined Behavior as per the C standard. Please don't tell me it is UB and there is nothing to talk about.

I'd like to know if there are compilers which won't have the expected behavior (defined by me below) for the following code.

Assume the size of `float` and `int` is 4 bytes, and a big-endian machine.

```
float f = 1234.567;  /* Any value here */
unsigned int u = *(unsigned int *)&f;
```

My expected behavior in english words is "get the four bytes where the `float` is stored and put them in an `int` *as is*". In code it would be this (I think there is no UB here):

```
float f = 1234.567;  /* Any value here */
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&f;
unsigned int u = (p[0] << 24) | (p[1] << 16) | (p[2] << 8) | p[3];
```

I'd also welcome practical and concrete examples of why, apart from being UB as per the standard, a compiler would have what I consider an unexpected behavior.

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to define the behaviour of _undefined behaviour_? Your very first sentence already states it clear. Note also your shifts invoke UB for certain values, too.

Comment: Some compilers have a *defined* behavior on certain c UB cases. I'd like to see an example of a compiler having a behavior different from my expected one in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762952/most-efficient-standard-compliant-way-of-reinterpreting-int-as-float

Comment: You should ask your compiler vendor.

Comment: @fukanchik: C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: @Olaf are you saying `memcpy` wouldn't be the right answer?

Comment: @fukanchik it is a good read but no it doesn't answer the question. I'm asking about this exact code, just curiosity

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out (often enough, so you can be very sure it *always* behaves like you think it should and did the first time :) )

Comment: I have it tested thoroughly in some compilers, with my expected behavior. But the wise people here might have counterexamples, or even reasons for having another behavior.

Comment: Jokes apart: Most (the older, the more) will behave like you expect. Some will not, some will cease to do that in their next minor release. What good would that knowledge be for? What good could any code be that *relies* on such stuff?

Comment: I went down the strict aliasing rabbit hole not very long ago and found this. It gets into the assembly and shows why UB can happen from violating strict aliasing .. if that's what you're asking: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On most compilers, it will do what you expect *until the optimizer decides to dead-code eliminate or move the assignment to f*.

This makes it essentially impossible to test if any given compiler will *always* do what you expect -- it might work for one particular program, but then a slightly different one might fail.  The strict-aliasing rule is basically just telling the compiler implementor "you can rearrange and eliminate these things fairly freely by assuming they never alias".  When it's not useful to do things that would cause this code to fail, the optimizer probably won't, so you won't see a problem.

Bottom line is that it is not *useful* to talk about "which compilers this will somtimes work on", as it might suddenly stop working in the future on any of them if something seemingly unrelated changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
float f = 1234.567;  /* Any value here */
unsigned int u = *(unsigned int *)&f;
```

Some plausible reasons why this would not work as expected are:

1. `float` and `unsigned int` are not the same size. (I've worked on systems where `int` is 64 bits and `float` is 32 bits. I've also worked on systems where both `int` and `float` are 64 bits, so your assumption that 4 bytes are copied would fail.)
2. `float` and `unsigned int` have different alignment requirements. Specifically, if `unsigned int` requires stricter alignment than `float`, and `f` happens to to be strictly aligned, reading `f` as if it were an `unsigned int` could do Bad Things. (This is *probably* unlikely if `int` and `float` are the same size.)
3. A compiler might recognize that the code's behavior is undefined, and for example optimize away the assignment. (I don't have a concrete example of this.)

If you want to copy the representation of a `float` into an `unsigned int`, `memcpy()` is safer (and I'd first check that they actually have the same size). If you want to examine the representation of a `float` object, the canonical way to do that is to copy it to an array of `unsigned char`. Quoting the ISO C standard (6.2.6.1p4 in the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft):

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
>   consist of *n* × **`CHAR_BIT`** bits, where *n* is the size of an
>   object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into an object
>   of type **`unsigned char [`** *n* **`]`** (e.g., by **`memcpy`**); the
>   resulting set of bytes is called the *object representation* of the
>   value.

Comment: I explicitly asked for an assumption for both being 4 bytes long, and was also thinking about them being equally aligned. But good point on 3, and interesting reference to the standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking undefined behavior for no reason at all.

> Will this strict-aliasing rule violation have the behavior I expect?

No. And you don't need to expect anything, because you can write much better looking code.

This has defined behavior that you'd like:

```
union {
  float f;
  uint32_t i;
} ufi_t;
assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t);

ufi_t u = { 123.456 };
uint32_t i = u.i;
```

You can factor it out, decent compilers will generate no code for it:

```
inline uint32_t int_from_float(float f) {
  ufi_t u = { f };
  return u.i;
}
```

You can also cast from (*float) to (*ufi_t) safely. So:

```
float f = 123.456;
uint32_t i = ((ufi_t*)&f)->i;
```

Note: language lawyers are welcome to set me straight on this last one, but that's what I make of [C9899:201x 6.5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf) and so on.

Comment: Nothing in the Standard would forbid an implementation from imposing an alignment requirement on union types which is coarser than the alignment requirement for any member contained therein.

Comment: @supercat Yep. And by golly would a lot of code break if someone did that :/

Comment: Given that the `union` trick isn't going to be reliable in the general case, compiler writers could easily regard the permission to use pointers of struct and union types as only allowing objects *with no declared type* to be created by writing their constituents.  If some storage with no declared type is written with an `int`, the rule would allow a compiler to retroactively regard its effective type as being a union containing that `int`.  Such allowance wouldn't work, though, if the object had a *declared* type of `int`.