# Easiest way to print 64 bit hex data splitted by 16 bits

Tags: c

I want to print 64 bits hex data in following format:

```
0x1111_2222_3333_4444
```

I can think of following:

```
#define FIRST_MASK  0xFFFF000000000000
#define SECOND_MASK 0x0000FFFF00000000
#define THIRD_MASK  0x00000000FFFF0000
#define FOURTH_MASK 0x000000000000FFFF

val = 0x1111222233334444 
printf("0x%04x_%04x_%04x_%04x\n", \
       (unsigned int)((val & FIRST_MASK)  >> 48),
       (unsigned int)((val & SECOND_MASK) >> 32),
       (unsigned int)((val & THIRD_MASK)  >> 16),
       (unsigned int)(val & FOURTH_MASK)
);
```

Is there a simple (or maybe more clean) way to achieve this?

Comment: ... a union with uint16_t[4]?

Comment: @technosaurus ...is a bad idea, because then the code turns endianess-dependent for nothing gained.

Comment: @technosaurus I personally consider this as sad but I somewhere found (in SO) that it is UB when reading components from a `union` which have not written before. (And, yes, this was very common in old code. This was discussed as well.) If I only could remember how I found this...

Comment: @Scheff You probably found it in some _C++_ discussion, as it is UB in C++ but not in C. At any rate, it doesn't matter, unions are bad in this case for a different reason: because of endianess.

Comment: Not sure if I should laugh or cry each time this topic pops up. Bit shifts are superior for splitting up a larger type, it is the best solution and that's not subjective or open for debate. Unions, bit-field structs or pointer arithmetic are inferior because of endianess and poorly-specified behavior. Yet there are _always_ people suggesting those solutions. Sigh.

Comment: @Lundin It's actually off-topic as pointed out by you (I agree) but it starts to pain me. I googled a little bit regarding "C union casting" and found some related Q/As for C as well as C++. However - none of them mentioned the resp. specification paragraph. Hence I wouldn't consider them as authoritative. I also saw a lot about aliasing but I think that isn't the same (as it might feel at first glance). And yes, that original topic (where I saw the answer _with_ reference to specification) - I cannot remember whether it was related to C or C++. Too bad...

Comment: @Scheff This is stated in behavior of the `.`/`->` operator. Specifically, C11 6.5.2.3/3 allows "type punning" through unions.

Comment: @Lundin "type punning" was the key word I just found out by myself. (I feel I'm coming closer.) Found this: [SO: Is type-punning through a union unspecified in C99, and has it become specified in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11639947/7478597).

Comment: You could improve `printf` yourself (in GCC, at least). Here you have some clue: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220581/200418

Answer (score 11):

Bit shifts are always the best method, because they are both fast and platform-independent. However, your code is needlessly complex: you can mask after shifting instead of before.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  uint64_t val = 0x1111222233334444;
  printf("0x%04x_%04x_%04x_%04x\n", 
         (unsigned int)(val>>48 & 0xFFFF),
         (unsigned int)(val>>32 & 0xFFFF),
         (unsigned int)(val>>16 & 0xFFFF),
         (unsigned int)(val>> 0 & 0xFFFF) );
}
```