# Why there is no warning due to overwriting union members in gcc?

Tags: linux, compilation, gcc, c

Assuming this code-snippet in file.c:

```
union numbers
  {
     int i;
     float f;
  };

union numbers first_number;

first_number.i = 5;
first_number.f = 3.9;

printf("%i %'.2f\n", first_number.i, first_number.f);
```

Why there is no warning that `first_number.i` is overwritten, after compile with `gcc -Wall file.c` and where does the resulting number of `first_number.i` is coming from?

A least, what is the general purpose of overwriting union members, ain't it better instead of to declare more union variables to avoid this behavior?

Comment: This is not a structure:  in a union, there is only one value at any given time.

Comment: That is the purpose of using a union.

Answer (score 2):

That's how C unions work. If you want non-overlapping fields, use a struct. The value of the `.i` member after storing a float value is the bit pattern interpreted as an int.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to conserve space (memory), when you need different fields at different times.

There is no extra space to record which field of the union was written last.   And so there is no way to automatically detect reading the "wrong" field, when the program is running.  The programmer must do so herself.  And in most cases, the compiler can't detect such reads either.

But even in the cases it *can* detect, GCC does not warn about this.  Why?

It is because C programmers sometimes *do* want to re-interpret type A in memory as type B.  We're weird like that.

GCC explicitly documents that you can re-interpret types - if you use a union.  As do other major compilers.  There is some confusion about whether the official C standards all managed to define this rule properly.  But everyone agrees what the rule is in practice.

https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307#comment-18418

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior

You might think you can use pointer casts instead of a union.  You would be wrong.  That behaviour is "undefined" by the standard.  The compiler can treat any code path where it would happen as impossible, and ignore it.  Then *anything* can happen.  This process is known as "optimization".

https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Users are advised not to think too hard about what it means if you start juggling pointers to different fields of a union, and just make sure they never do that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified#comment61928962_11640381

C++ users should use `reinterpret_cast<>` instead.  It is also alleged that standard C++ does not support re-interpreting types with a `union`.