# C uniion efficiency on same sized types

Tags: c, unions

Are unions around same sized types less efficient, then access by pointers?

```
union u {
  long i;
  float f;
}
```

Comment: "when" accessed via pointers?

Comment: A decent compiler will do nothing at all for the union, except to note the aliasing,  Conversely type punning via pointers is probably actually *incorrect* because of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @JeffHolt I think he means casting to change the type instead of using a union.

Comment: Why not compile two variations and then disassemble the object code? You'll probably find out that they're the same.

Comment: What are you actually using this for?  There don't tend to be hard-and-fast rules like "construct X is always more efficient than construct Y".

Comment: There is a discussion of this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#C_and_C++

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified

Comment: @JeffHolt: Compiling and disassembling two variations generally will not reveal the behavior of one of them is undefined by the C standard. Even if two variations result in the same generated code, that does not mean they have the same semantics according to the C standard.

Comment: Unions are data types.  Access is an action.  These are not comparable.  What action involving unions do you seek to compare to what specific variation on access via a pointer?  Example code would be a good way to convey this.

Answer (score 1):

No, using a union to reinterpret an object as another type is not inherently less efficient than doing so by aliasing using pointers and has the advantage that it is defined by the C standard, whereas aliasing using pointers is generally not.