# Has atomic type-punning through unions defined behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, atomic, unions, type-punning

[Type-punning through unions has defined behaviour in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11639947/420683):

```
typedef union
{
    uint32_t i;
    float f;
} MyUnion;

MyUnion u;
u.f = 4.2;
print("%"PRIu32, u.i); // defined behaviour
```

Given via a footnote in the C Standard:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the
> object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new
> type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation.

---

However, is it still defined behaviour when atomic operations are used? And what is that behaviour? Do we have some of the sequencing guarantees?

```
typedef union
{
    _Atomic uint32_t i;
    _Atomic float f; // assume sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)
} MyUnion;

int load(MyUnion* p)
{
    atomic_load(&p->i);
}

void store(MyUnion* p)
{
    return atomic_store(&p->i, 42);
}
```

You can also construct strange examples like:

```
typedef union
{
    _Atomic uint32_t i;
    struct
    {
        uint16_t h0; // or maybe _Atomic uint16_t ah0;
        _Atomic uint16_t ah1;
    };
} MyUnion;
```

---

6.5.2.3p5 at least says:

> Accessing a member of an atomic structure or union object results in undefined behavior.

```
typedef _Atomic union
{
    uint32_t i;
    float f;
} MyUnion;

int load(MyUnion* p)
{
    return atomic_load(&p->i); // UB, also atomic_load on non-atomic type
    return p->i; // UB
}
```

Comment: While the type punning itself is well-defined, it's nonsense to re-interpret a float as an int and vice versa, regardless of `_Atomic`. The conversion might raise floating point exceptions for example.

Comment: I don't know a formal answer here, but I strongly suspect your code is not well defined.  Anyway, I'd think it would be simpler and safer to just use a single type for your `_Atomic` object, say `int`, and then code that wants to pun it as `float` should just load the `int` value and run it through its own private `union`.  Vice versa for a store.

Comment: It does mean that you won't get access to atomic arithmetic operators on `float`, e.g.  `fetch_add`.  But those are usually implemented as a CAS loop anyway, and so you could just write it yourself with `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` on the `int`.

Comment: @Lundin: Not "nonsense", surely.  It's implementation-defined, but most implementations define their representations of `int` and `float` very carefully, and so you often see this construct in code meant for particular implementations.  If you construct your `int` value correctly, you can be sure of what you will get, and that you won't get any sort of trap or exception.  But surely you know that?

Comment: There would most certainly be data race problems if either `int` or `float` were not lock-free, or if they were of different sizes.  So I find it unlikely that C guarantees anything at all in general about atomicity here.

Comment: @NateEldredge Using _signed_ `int` to express the raw binary representation of something is always nonsense. For such purposes you would use `uint32_t`/`unsigned int`. Signed floats do not "sign extend" in the same manner as 2's complement `int`, so all manner of subtle bugs are possible as soon as you involve bitwise operators or other arithmetic.

Comment: ... and I was just trying to make the example a bit simpler by using `int` instead of `uint32_t`. I know it doesn't make a lot of sense, the code which I encountered "in the wild" was more like the union of `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 0):

> is it still defined behaviour when atomic operations are used?

The same conditions apply. It may be a trap representation, and `_Atomic` objects may differ in size, representation, alignment compared to the unqualified types. If it is not a trap representation, then the result will be (implementation-) defined.

Comment: But do the synchronization guarantees on atomics apply? E.g. a load-acquire on the float and a store-release on the int.

Comment: And that is the real question ;) . I believe this will be either under-specified and undefined behavior by omission, or just undefined, (or implementation defined at best). I do not believe it would be sane to expect synchronization on type-punned atomics. _Atomic (theoretically) may have some additional data and hidden fields, so `union { _Atomic char c; _Atomic int i; }` and accessing both of them at the same time will just be trouble.